# runtime error while using invert() or inv() to invert a matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix-inverse

I'm trying to invert a matrix in opencv. There are no build errors, but I keep getting "Unsupported format or combination of formats () in unknown function, file ..\..\..\..\ocv\opencv\modules\core\src\lapack.cpp, line 1469", which doesn't help much to understand what am I doing wrong.
I'm using the following code:

```
Mat centerPointsMat = Mat(5, 3, CV_32SC2);
Mat centerPointsMatInv = Mat(5, 3, CV_32SC2);
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    Point p1=Point(0,i);
    centerPointsMat.at<float>(p1) = ((CvPoint*)CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(CvPoint,centerPointsSeq,i))->x^2;
    Point p2=Point(1,i);
    centerPointsMat.at<float>(p2) = ((CvPoint*)CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM(CvPoint,centerPointsSeq,i))->x;
    Point p3=Point(2,i);
    centerPointsMat.at<float>(p3) = 1;
}
centerPointsMatInv = centerPointsMat.inv(1);
```

The same using invert() instead of inv() produces the same result.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You can only invert a square matrix -- and even then you almost never want to (inversion is frequently quite unstable numerically, so even when it should theoretically work, the results it produces won't be very accurate).

Comment: You need a float or double, square matrix

Comment: Thanks vasile! changing CV_32SC2 to CV_32FC1 seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 4):

Only non-singular, square, positive definite matrices can have inverses..

Please see [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_of_a_matrix) for more information

Comment: That's all correct, but invert() can also handle singular, non-square matrices. The following is from http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html : "When the matrix src is singular or non-square, the function computes the pseudo-inverse matrix, i.e. the matrix dst , such that is minimal... In the case of DECOMP_SVD method, the function returns the inversed condition number of src (the ratio of the smallest singular value to the largest singular value) and 0 if src is singular. The SVD method calculates a pseudo-inverse matrix if src is singular."

Comment: This anwer is wrong in this context. OpenCV provides the pseudo-inverse matrix.

Comment: pseudo-inverse is not equal to inverse for singular. if non-singular you dont need pseudo.

Answer (score 2):

Like vasile here pointed out, invert() only supports double or float matrix types. Changing my matrix type from CV_32SC2 to CV_32FC1 seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some critera that has to be followed to use the simple `invert` function as pointed out by previous answers. Firstly, the matrix has to be 32-float type.

But the invert function can have a third parameter which is a flag, that tells what kind of algorithm behind the invert is done:

`DECOMP_LU`, `DECOMP_SVD` and `DECOMP_CHOLESKY` are the thre types used.

From the opencv-3.0 documentation:

> The function invert inverts the matrix src and stores the result in
>   dst . When the matrix src is singular or non-square, the function
>   calculates the pseudo-inverse matrix (the dst matrix) so that
>   norm(src*dst - I) is minimal, where I is an identity matrix.
>
> In case of the DECOMP_LU method, the function returns non-zero value
>   if the inverse has been successfully calculated and 0 if src is
>   singular.
>
> In case of the DECOMP_SVD method, the function returns the inverse
>   condition number of src (the ratio of the smallest singular value to
>   the largest singular value) and 0 if src is singular. The SVD method
>   calculates a pseudo-inverse matrix if src is singular.
>
> Similarly to DECOMP_LU , the method DECOMP_CHOLESKY works only with
>   non-singular square matrices that should also be symmetrical and
>   positively defined. In this case, the function stores the inverted
>   matrix in dst and returns non-zero. Otherwise, it returns 0.